# Call an activity method from a BroadcastReceiver. Is it possible?

Tags: android, methods, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I'm stuck developing an app because I need to call a method of my activity when a BroadcastReceiver is triggered. I want the BroadcastReceiver to detect when a network connection goes down and call a method of my activity which I've already written.

I've been searching and I found that more people had asked this before but nobody got an answer about how to do it.

I think that maybe android's API doesn't allow it. If it's impossible to call a method of my activity from the BroadcastReceiver are there other ways to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: What does the method on your `Activity` do?

Comment: It checks if a Process variable (which belongs to the Activity) isn't set to null (the process has started) and it executes a command in a root shell which kills that process.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try something like this..

In you activity code write

```
BroadcastReceiver connectionReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            myActivityMethod();// Here you call method
        }
    };

    registerReceiver(connectionReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.test.NET_CONNECTION"));
```

And in your service write

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.test.NET_CONNECTION");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
```

If any confusion let me know i'll try to solve..

Comment: Even though I don't use a service (only an activity) I used the code in the activity and ommited the code for the service. It worked nicely. Thank you very much for your help! This issue had been driving me crazy for a couple of days.