# How to Call an activity method from a BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android

I am currently developing an app, I need to call an activity method from BroadcastReceiver.

My app is to when the user getting a call Broadcast receiver find that and send a message to that particular number.

I am able to get that no, but I want to send a message to that number, for this sending sms I created an activity in side sending sms method is there..

How do I call that particular method from my BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: what if your activity is closed?

Comment: yeah...bad practice. better use a Service or put the receiver in your activity

Comment: I figuer it , see this link :
[Call an activity method from a BroadcastReceiver class][1]


and : [Call an activity method from a BroadcastReceiver. Is it possible?][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16934425/call-an-activity-method-from-a-broadcastreceiver-class
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104235/call-an-activity-method-from-a-broadcastreceiver-is-it-possible?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You need to make that method `static and public inside your activity`.You can call that method like this:

```
ActivityName.mehtodName();
```

It will be much better if you put that method in your util class and call it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **Callback** using an interface for calling that the activity method from `BroadcastReceiver`

```
interface MyCallback{

      public void doStuff();

}
```

**Provide the CallBack in the BroadcastReceiver**

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

   private MyCallback callback;

   public MyBroadcastReceiver(MyCallback callback){

       this.callback = callback;          //<-- Initialse it

   } 

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

       callback.doStuff();                //<--- Invoke callback method
   }

}
```

**Now implement the Callback in your Activity and override the method**

```
MyActvity extends AppcompatActivity implements MyCallback {

   // Your Activity related code //
   // new MyBroadcastReceiver(this);    <-- this is how you create instance

   private void sendSMS(){
     // your logic to send SMS
   } 


   @Override 
   public void doStuff(){
     sendSMS();          //<--- Call the method to show alert dialog
   }

}
```

> You can read the advantage of using this approach [here in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643385/how-to-update-ui-in-a-broadcastreceiver/54364171#54364171)