# Call an activity method from a BroadcastReceiver class

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, inner-classes

I know I can do an inner receiver class to call any method from my receiver

But my main activity is too damn big and does a lot of things. 
So I will need a class that extends broadcast receiver but who isn't an inner class. And can call one method from my main activity. I don't know if it's possible but my activity is a Home activity and a "singleInstance" activity so maybe with this detail someone has a way to access to my activity.

If it's impossible any way to split some java code in multiple files my main have more than 600 lines. (and for information I have already 19 java files for an alpha version of my apps so I have try to split it)

Comment: can't you pass the activity context to your BrodcastRecevier and use it to start the activity?

Comment: The activity is always launch i don't want to launch it from receiver just call a method

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Create the BroadcastReceiver dynamically:

In your BroadcastReceiver class define class member:

```
YourMainActivity yourMain = null;
```

and method:

```
setMainActivityHandler(YourMainActivity main){
yourMain = main;
}
```

from your MainActivity do:

```
private YourBroadcastReceiverClassName yourBR = null;
yourBR = new YourBroadcastReceiverClassName();
    yourBR.setMainActivityHandler(this);    
    IntentFilter callInterceptorIntentFilter = new           IntentFilter("android.intent.action.ANY_ACTION");
    registerReceiver(yourBR,  callInterceptorIntentFilter);
```

finally, when yourBR.onReceive is fired you can call:

```
yourMain.methodOfMainActivity();
```

Comment: Need i define my action in Manifest with this method or intentfilter is enough to get the broadcast?

Comment: Ok thanks i try this. just edit your post change callInterceptor by yourBR in registerReceiver call if another one read this :P

Answer (score 3):

#Make your BroadcastReceiver independent of Activity
[image]
Making a `BroadcastReceiver` inner class of an `Activity` so that it can access UI elements from its `onReceive()` method just does not make sense. If you do so you can not reuse the `BroadcastReceiver` with any other activity. And you will end up writing almost same code again and again.
A better way of doing this would be, **make a Callback for `BroadcastReceiver` and let Your Activity subscribe this Callback**.

> How do I do that?

**1) Create a CallBack interface**

```
public interface ReceiverCallback{

      public void doSomething(Object object);

}
```

**2) Provide your Callback in the BroadcastReceiver**

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

     private ReceiverCallback callback;

     public MyBroadcastReceiver(ReceiverCallback callback){

          this.callback = callback;        //<--Initialize this
     }

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  
           // Your listening logic goes here (New WIFI Scan data available, 
                                              Headphone plugged in etc)              

          // Send any data or No data(null)
          callback.doSomething(null);             //<--Send callback event

     }
}
```

**3) Subscribe Your Activity for CallBack events:**

```
public YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ReceiverCallback{

      // Your Activity code 

      public void updateUI() {     //<-- You want this to get Triggered 
             // Update UI code 
      }

      @Override
      public void doSomething(Object object){     
            updateUI();            //<-- Callback does that
      }

}
```

##Relevant Link:
Read a more detailed discussion [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643385/how-to-update-ui-in-a-broadcastreceiver/54364171#54364171)