# Unable to call BroadcastReceiver from AsyncTask of fragment

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-broadcast

So in fragment class, I have a `AsyncTask` class and there I am calling `BroadcastReceiver` at `onPostExecute()` method of `AsyncTask` -

**Android Manifest -**

```
        <receiver 
            android:name="com.iddl.main.IncomingBBStream"
            android:label="IncomingBBStream">   
             <action android:name="com.iddl.main.BBbroadcast" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.
                 device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

**Fragment Class -**

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
{   
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setAction("com.iddl.main.BBbroadcast");
  intent.putExtra("uuid", uuid);
  getActivity().sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

**BroadcastReceiver Class -**

```
public class IncomingBBStream extends BroadcastReceiver {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
   Log.i(TAG, "onReceive BroadcastReceiver------");
}
```

It should at least print the log message but it not doing so.

**NOTE:**

I have to add `intent.setClass(getActivity(), IncomingBBStream.class);` to get it work but that doesn't make sense because I already passed the action `"com.iddl.main.BBbroadcast"` that matches with the manifest's receiver name `"com.iddl.main.IncomingBBStream"`. So it knows which class to call.

Comment: have a look on this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923207/call-activity-method-from-broadcast-receiver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably want to do that:

```
<receiver
  android:name="com.iddl.main.IncomingBBStream"
  android:label="IncomingBBStream">

  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.iddl.main.BBbroadcast"/>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
  </intent-filter>

  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.bluetooth.
             device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED"/>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

each intent filter separate on its own tag and always include the default category.

Comment: Putting the action `"com.iddl.main.BBbroadcast"` inside `intent-filter` is giving warning in android manifest that `Exported receiver does not require permission`. This was the reason that I placed it outside of `intent-filter` tag.

Comment: it's just a warning. And it's a very silly one. Just do it, compile, run and test to see. ps: You probably want to add `exported="false"` on your receiver. That way outside applications can't send it.