# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method FloatingActionButton.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

I am trying to change the image of a floating action button when the app detects an in coming phone call. Here is the java class

```
public class PhoneCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

Main2Activity main2Activity;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String state= intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);


    if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {

        main2Activity=new Main2Activity();
        main2Activity.pauseWorkout();


    }

}
```

}

Inside the pauseWorkout method it contains a method call to another method that changes the image of the floating action button, **and it is where the exception is pointing at**. Here is the method:

```
public void showPlayButton() {

    //CHANGING FLOATING ACTION BUTTON

    startPauseFAB.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_white);
    startPauseFAB.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.floating_action_button_color_play)));
    startPauseFAB.setRippleColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.myGreen));


}
```

startPauseFAB.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_white); is where the problem is.
In the main2Activity the image changes from play to pause icons with no problem but when a call is ringing the app crushes. Here is how it is intitialized on onCreate:

```
        startPauseFAB = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.startAndPauseFAB);
```

And here is the xml for the floating action button:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/startAndPauseFAB"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/play_white"
                    app:backgroundTint="@color/floating_action_button_color_play"
                    app:borderWidth="0dp"
                    app:elevation="8dp"
                    app:fabSize="normal" />
```

I tried to use the debugging tool at **startPauseFAB.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_white);** it says there is no value.

here is the error message :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.leonk.workouttimerv1, PID: 13567
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.leonk.workouttimerv1.classes.PhoneCallReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2630)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:151)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1387)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.leonk.workouttimerv1.Main2Activity.setFABButton(Main2Activity.java:1308)
                  at com.example.leonk.workouttimerv1.classes.PhoneCallReceiver.onReceive(PhoneCallReceiver.java:27)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2623)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1387) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
```

How can I solve this problem. I searched through similar questions but the solutions didn't help

Comment: In which place do you init it ? Check if "startPauseFAB" is not null after initializing.

Comment: "main2Activity=new Main2Activity();" Don't do that. This main2Activity will never be displayed, so its onCreate() will not be called, so setContentView() will not run so no variable referencing a View will have a value different from null

Comment: You'll have to *start* the Activity from the Broadcast using Context.startActivity()

Comment: I think since you are instantiating main2activity like a regular class that oncreate is never called if you use context.startActivity in your broadcastreciever and pass a string or something then you call pauseWorkout in the activity

Comment: @JRowan and 0X0nosugar you all make valid points, context.startActivity will start the activity again and I just want it to remain on the same activity since a process is occurring so  that it just changes the image. Is there a way to initialize it again?

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923207/call-activity-method-from-broadcast-receiver

Comment: @JRowan I tried it out but it didn't work but at the same time lead me to find a solution posting the answer right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the phoneCallReceiver java class in the onReceive method I add the method call context.sendBroadCast with an intent as follows

```
public class PhoneCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {





@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String state= intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);


    if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {



    context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("PHONE_RING"));

    }

}
```

}

Then on the mainActivity create an object of the phoneCallReceiver class and override the onReceive method then call the activity method to change the image like :

```
 PhoneCallReceiver phoneCallReceiver=new PhoneCallReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        pauseWorkout();

    }
};
```

Then on onCreate register the receiver like so:

```
        registerReceiver(phoneCallReceiver,new IntentFilter("PHONE_RING"));
```

Then destroy :

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(phoneCallReceiver);

}
```

Solution I got it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241705/calling-a-activity-method-from-broadcastreceiver-in-android) : Thanks everyone who commented you helped a lot

> Blockquote